# How to find the height of the entire webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot, fullscreen, webpage-screenshot

I am working on a solution capturing screen-shots of websites. I am using the default example mentioned at slimerjs.org to get the job done.

Screen-shots are great with this tool, but I need to take full height screen-shots of websites. When capturing screens of websites like http://www.yellowpages.com, I can get full length screens without having to mention any height parameter.

But when I try this url: http://votingbecause.usatoday.com/

I only get screenshot of the set resolution (default: 1920x1080), I can't get full length images.

Since I am using slimerjs, I can manipulate the dom by using jQuery. I need to find complete website height so that I can take screenshot of that resolution

I tried

- document.height()
- document.body.scrollheight
- screen.height
- $(document).height()
- (and many other which i found)

But all of these only gave the height of the viewport (website in view)

Question is, how to find the full scrollable height of the website?

Comment: To provide a good question, you should put relevant source code so far and all information directly into the the question. When a linked site goes down, the question becomes worthless.

Comment: i apologize for this, but the main question was to get the height of the website, i guess i shouldn't have mentioned why i needed the height parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more general and find the height of **any page** you could just find the highest DOM Node on current page with a simple recursion:

```
;(function() {
    var pageHeight = 0;

    function findHighestNode(nodesList) {
        for (var i = nodesList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nodesList[i].scrollHeight && nodesList[i].clientHeight) {
                var elHeight = Math.max(nodesList[i].scrollHeight, nodesList[i].clientHeight);
                pageHeight = Math.max(elHeight, pageHeight);
            }
            if (nodesList[i].childNodes.length) findHighestNode(nodesList[i].childNodes);
        }
    }

    findHighestNode(document.documentElement.childNodes);

    // The entire page height is found
    console.log('Page height is', pageHeight);
})();
```

You can test it on your sample site(http://votingbecause.usatoday.com/) with pasting this script to a DevTools Console.

Enjoy!

P.S. Supports `iframe` content.

Comment: just a doubt, does this work with websites using iframes?

Answer (score 5):

Updated Answer for **2020**:

You can just simply pass this below line to get the Height of the Webpage

***Code:***

```
console.log("Page height:",document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 3):

The contents in the site are in the following div

```
<div class="site-wrapper flex column">
```

use this code to get it's height

```
document.querySelector(".site-wrapper").scrollHeight
```

Comment: this is great, but is there a generic solution to finding the height , so it works for other websites too?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any direct way of achieving it. Every website will have different container for their content and they could be nested within other elements like in the site you gave.

Answer (score 1):

try windows.innerHeight to get browser viewport size
i think that is what you are loking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").height();
```

is what you need

Comment: i tried this, i am only getting the height of the website in view, the height of the above website should be nearly 5000 px

Comment: the second page is 1536px heigh not 5000px.

Comment: @iHasCodeForU how did u get that value, please tell :D
when i set 5000 px in the tool i made, i get the full website screenshot,so i assumed it was 5000px

Comment: i opened "inspect element" and clicked on the body tag. in the left bottom corner it said the dimensions for me. (opera browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();
```

retrieve current window height..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that worked.
`document.body.scrollHeight`
was giving me a value of 0.
What worked was

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

https://minimul.com/getting-a-zero-with-document-body-scrollheight.html