# Is there any way to get height of document in angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use value of height of whole document in my angular application. But everything i'm trying to use returns height of my viewport (e.g. scrollHeight, clientHeight, offsetHeight). Is there any way to find out height of whole page content ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the height of the entire webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179264/how-to-find-the-height-of-the-entire-webpage)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `document.body.clientHeight`.